# Switching themes in android

Tags: java, android, themes

My aim is to allow users select from a list of available themes in my app and make it permanent till they wish to change it again, but i have only been able to achieve that partially. For now, when a user changes the app theme it does change and remains even after the app is minimized and resumed but when a user exits the app and reopens it, the theme goes back to default which is not what i want.

My question now is, how can i make the selected theme permanent even when a user exits the app? I have tried to search for some solutions online but haven't found any that helped me

`ThemeActivity.java`

```
public class ThemeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public Button blackbtn,bluebtn,pinkbtn,redbtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    themeUtils.onActivityCreateSetTheme(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_theme);


    blackbtn = findViewById(R.id.blackbutton);
    bluebtn = findViewById(R.id.bluebutton);
    pinkbtn = findViewById(R.id.pinkbutton);
    redbtn = findViewById(R.id.redbutton);

    blackbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            themeUtils.changeToTheme(ThemeActivity.this, themeUtils.BLACK);
        }
    });

    bluebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            themeUtils.changeToTheme(ThemeActivity.this, themeUtils.BLUE);
        }
    });

    pinkbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            themeUtils.changeToTheme(ThemeActivity.this, themeUtils.PINK);
        }
    });

    redbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            themeUtils.changeToTheme(ThemeActivity.this, themeUtils.RED);
        }
    });

}
```

`themeUtils.java`

```
public class themeUtils {

private static int cTheme;
public final static int BLACK = 0;
public final static int BLUE = 1;
public final static int PINK = 2;
public final static int RED = 3;


public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme) {

    cTheme = theme;
    activity.finish();
    activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));

}

public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity) {
    switch (cTheme)
    {
        default:

        case BLACK:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.BlackTheme);

            break;

        case PINK:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.pink);

            break;

        case RED:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.red);

            break;

        case BLUE:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.BlueTheme);

            break;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution for this would be to save your selected theme in **SharedPreferences**. Whenever the app launches, you read the saved value from your SharedPreferences and load the appropriate theme.

To write your selected theme

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.selected_app_theme), YOUR_APP_THEME);
editor.commit();
```

To read the saved value

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.default_app_theme);
int appTheme = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.selected_app_theme), defaultValue);
```

**EDIT Based on comment**

Whenever you change your app theme, you need to save it to SharedPreferences. So, whenever the *changeToTheme* method is called, after changing the theme, just save it to SharedPrefs. You could create a method which would save the theme like so

```
void saveThemeToSharedPrefs(int appTheme) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt("MY_APP_THEME, appTheme);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Next time, when your app starts, you will load this value and use it to change the theme like so

```
int getAppTheme() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int defaultValue = 0    //For Black theme. Change it to whatever you want as default
    int appTheme = sharedPref.getInt("MY_APP_THEME", defaultValue);
}

//Change the theme in your starting activity
ThemeUtils.changeToTheme(activity, getAppTheme())
```

Comment: please can you simply it more to me? in which activity or class should i read or write to sharedpreference and which value should i save to sharedpreference according to the two classes in my question.